# What happens to your data if the WHS machine fails?

Tags: backup, windows-home-server

If the WHS machine fails, are the harddrives still readable by any machine or do you have to go out get another WHS machine before you can recover your data?

Comment: If your data doesn't exist in at least 3 places you can't honestly say it's backed up. Failure of a single point shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as long as it isn't the hard drive that fails, your data should be safe and readable in any other machine.

The only requirement would be that it has to be a Windows based machine if you are using Software Raid - and because of this, you will be limited to Windows Server editions or Windows Vista/7 Enterprise/Professional/Ultimate.

Comment: i think that's the real crux of the question -- what storage types are typically used in WHS, and do those storage types migrate.  to that end, you're spot on about software raid.